Display MVT vector tiles from PostGIS ST_AsMVT
I am trying to generate tiles on the fly from a PostGIS db using this query:
SELECT encode(ST_AsMVT(mvtgeom.*, 'admin', 4096), 'base64')
-- SELECT ST_AsMVT(mvtgeom.*)
FROM (
    SELECT ST_AsMVTGeom(
             ground_geometry,
             ST_TileEnvelope(15,17473,10896 )) AS geom
    FROM   cjdb.city_object
) mvtgeom

This does generate mvt tiles which I can view in QGIS for example. The issue is, that the tile seems to be translated to 0,0, so each tile is located in 0,0 and has no projection information.
When I upload the generated tile for example here: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/drag-and-drop-custom-mvt.html
it lays somewhere in the middle of nowhere.
Is that correct, or do I somehow need to write the zxy values to the MVT in order to know where it is?

That's how MVT tiles work https://github.com/mapbox/vector-tile-spec/tree/master/2.1#43-geometry-encoding. Each tile has origin at (0,0). For locating the tile on the ground user must know also the z, x, y values of the tile, and what kind of tiling schema is used. The tiling schema is often defined with a json document. See https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/mvt.html#metadata-json. The EPSG:3857 Web Mercator schema is the most common.

Hey if you just want a solution for serving vector tiles, look at pg_tileserv https://access.crunchydata.com/documentation/pg_tileserv/1.0.8/
